# Greens Theorem to Evaluate curve $2\lvert x\rvert + \lvert y\rvert = 1$

Tags: greens-theorem

Trying to evaluate the function $(x^3 + y^3)\,\mathrm{d}x + (x^3 - y^3)\,\mathrm{d}y$ over the curve $2\lvert x\rvert + \lvert y\rvert = 1$ using greens theorem. The correct answer is $-3/8$ which I get only if I double integrate over one out of the four of the triangles. I thought the answer multiplies by four because of symmetry?

Comment: $2|x|+|x|=3|x|$?

Comment: $3|x| = 1 \Rightarrow x = \pm \frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: Edited Typo @GoodDeeds

Comment: Edited Typo @MarcPaul

Comment: Yes, that looks more reasonable. Perhaps you should also include your calculation, because without seeing your previous steps, we can only guess why your answer is 4 times lower than the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curl $Q_x-P_y=3(x^2-y^2)$ is symmetric with respect to $x$ and $y$. Therefore it is sufficient to compute
$$4\int_0^{1/2}\int_0^{1-2x}3(x^2-y^2)\>dy\>dx\ ,$$
and the result is indeed $-{3\over8}$.